# Create serial primery key for splited table

Tags: postgresql, alter, postgresql-11

I have archive table and production table with the same schema.
Production has a fresh data and archive has old data.
I would like to add `id` to them as a serial primery key.
In both tables I have data.
My idea is to create id in a archive table.

```
alter table people add column id serial primary key;
```

Then do the same in my production table.
Production is a continuation of archive table so `primery key` should also be continuation for it.
So I used:

```
alter sequence people_id_seq restart with 40;
```

My only issue is this commend doesn't update index. Only set start value for new inserts.
So should I first run

```
UPDATE people set id = id + 40;
```

And the set sequence with value of number of all rows (in archive and production).

```
alter sequence people_id_seq restart with (40 + select count(*) from people);
```

I have a few tables for this process (with diffrent number of rows in archive and production) so I'm looking for the most automative solution for this.

Comment: Might be easier to use UUIDs instead

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you elaborate how to use UUID in this case?